# Identifying & modifying single field in Django Model

Tags: django, post, model

I'm using Django to build a small system to control the lending and borrowing of some stuff our Students Café lend to students.
**I'm having trouble identifying an object after a form submit**, I want to mark the object as 'unaivalable' (disponible means available, so I want to set it to False) so next time someone comes to ask for THAT object, it will not show up in the 'lending' form.

*All I need is a hint on how to achieve it, I've been looking through Django docs, and this site, with no success. Thanks in advance for the tips!*

**models.py**

```
class Mate(models.Model):
color = models.CharField(max_length=2,
    choices=COLOR_CHOICES, default=u'RO')
disponible = models.BooleanField(default=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.color


class Prestamo(models.Model):
cliente = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=False, blank=False)
mate = models.ForeignKey(Mate, null=False, blank=False)
termo = models.ForeignKey(Termo, null=False, blank=False)
bombilla = models.ForeignKey(Bombilla, null=False, blank=False)
fecha = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
devuelto = models.BooleanField(default=False)
fecha_devolucion = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.pk)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
# Add_prestamo means 'Add lending' this basically deals with prestamo model, but i want to alter 'mate' objects here too.
def add_prestamo(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PrestamoForm(request.POST,
            auto_id=False, error_class=DivErrorList)

    if form.is_valid():
        prestamo = form.save(commit=False)

        if request.POST.get('usuarios'):
            miuser = request.POST.get('usuarios', '')
        else:
            miuser = ''
        prestamo.cliente = Usuario.objects.get(nombre__exact=miuser)

        # I KINDA NEED SOMETHING RIGHT HERE

        prestamo.fecha = timezone.now()
        prestamo.devuelto = False
        prestamo.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list-prestamos'))
else:
    form = PrestamoForm()
return TemplateResponse(request,
         'gester/add_prestamo.html', {'form': form, })
```

**add_prestamo.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="ui-widget">
                  <label for="usuarios">Usuario: </label></td><td>
                  <input id="usuarios" name="usuarios">
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Crear" />
</form>
```

In the template I show the form with a {{ form.as_table }} it display a select, but many of them (mates) have the same color, so when I get through POST in my view, how do I identify the exact object to alter the 'disponible' field value?

Comment: Does Mate have a primary key? If so, you can use that to update the Mate model. Kind of like: `Mate.objects.filter(pk = request.POST.get('mate')).update(disponible=False)`

Comment: Is `PrestamoForm` a modelform, or a form?

Comment: It is a PrestamoForm JackShedd
Thanks @BrandonBertelsen, I was travelling an hour after I post this and meanwhile reading a book I came up with a solution like catherine posted, although I was looking for something more like you did (couldn't make it work because I never realized I can mix a POST string with a pk).

Comment: I'm still amazed by your answer Brandon, it not only answers my questions, besides it makes me dig deeper into related objects/pk in Django. I thought I readed enough but you made me realize I was barely understanding how this amazing framework works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand your codes but because you mention disponible, I hope this is what you mean.

```
prestamo.fecha = timezone.now()
prestamo.devuelto = False

//Because Prestamo model has a foreignkey for Mate model. 
//The Mate model contains the disponible field which you want to access 
//     (to set it to False or unavailable)?
//This is how to access and update it.
prestamo.mate.disponible = False
prestamo.mate.save()

prestamo.save()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Catherine. If you mean you couldn't understand because it is in spanish, that's because i started coding everything in english, and then i had a hard time finding good translations for regional stuff (the kind of stuff that is the main part of the system, MATE, which is a regional drink, for example).
I came up with the same you posted by myself, but when I came home and read your answer, I was glad that someones cares enough to help me solve such a simple issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I will answer anything as long as I can solved it and if I have a free time :)